# Getting an error when clicking a link element on a web page by a Selenium script

Tags: selenium

When my Selenium script clicks a link element presented on a web page by  `click()` method, I am getting the below error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Element is not clickable at point (36, 72).
```

This is my HTML code

```
<div id="targettab"> 
<a href="Default.aspx" id="highlight-book">Book</a>
</div>
```

This is my Selenium code:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("highlight-book")).click();
```

What am I doing wrong here? Could you please advise me about possible solutions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If element is present in lot of nested divs, rarely selenium driver will fails to click element. You can try clicking using Enter button.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("highlight-book")).sendKeys(Keys.Return);
```